# Android Encryption porting

Tags: encryption

I'm currently trying to enable the full disk encryption in Android on my custom board. 
Some informations:

- The /data Partition is the 4th Partition on my SD Card.
- after the /data Partition there is >2MB free space
- the /data Partition is ext4

If I run `vdc cryptfs enablecrypto inplace 1234` I get

```
logcat | grep crypt
E/Cryptfs ( 2407): Orig filesystem overlaps crypto footer region.  Cannot encrypt in place.
```

If I run `vdc cryptfs enablecrypto wipe 1234` I get

```
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: table: 254:0: crypt: Error creating IV
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

and the device reboots afterwards...

Some extended information:
fstab

```
cat /fstab.boundary
....
$BD4    /data    ext4    nosuid,nodev,nodiratime,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic    wait,encryptable=footer
....
```

init.rc

```
cat /init.boundary.rc
...
mount_all /fstab.boundary
...
```

Screenshot from the partition layout:
[image: Screenshot from the partition layout]

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the wrong parameter in your fstab. You can't place the footer in space already reserved for a filesystem. Either make an extra partition (sdc5) and specify footer=/dev/sdc5:0 (to put it at the beginning of this partition) or specify a negative offset to use the space at the end of the partition, e.g. to use 16k of the partition specify: encryptable=footer,length=-16384

Not sure if you'd need to make your ext4 filesystem not smaller than the partition, otherwise it could overwrite your footer.